# PySpark: date interval in PySpark's sequence function?

Tags: pyspark

I want to generate a DataFrame with dates using PySpark's `sequence()` function (not looking for work-arounds using other methods).  I got this working with the default step of 1.  But how do I generate a sequence with dates, say, 1 week apart?  I can't figure out what type/value to feed into the `step` parameter of the function.

```
df =  (spark.createDataFrame([{'date':1}])
      .select(explode(sequence(to_date(lit('2021-01-01')),to_date(lit(date.today())))).alias('calendar_date')))
df.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an INTERVAL literal. From your code:

```
df = (
    spark
    .createDataFrame([{'date':1}])
    .select(
        explode(sequence(
            to_date(lit('2021-01-01')), # start
            to_date(lit(date.today())), # stop
            expr("INTERVAL 1 WEEK")     # step
        )).alias('calendar_date')
    )
)

df.show()
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-literals.html#interval-literal

Comment: heh, I thought I had tried something like this before asking the questions and it didn't work.  Thanks!  I'm going to try to figure out what Python native class `expr("INTERVAL 1 WEEK")` resolves to.  I wonder if there is a way to do this directly without resorting to `eval()`